# OnClick, OnMouseDown, <a>, and such will not work

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I am working on a game app in javascript. So far everything seems to be working.
Here is the last working version:
http://dylanmadigan.net/_digital-work/game-2/5-tilt/index.html

I've changed some things in terms of graphics since then. Everything was working quite well. I am now working on adding a menu in the game.

So I added my menu and for some reason I cannot make the "play button" work. I tried onclick, onMouseDown, onMouseup, and adding an `<a>` tag around it. I also tried just having the play button link to facebook rather than a javascript function and even that wouldn't work. It appears any sort of click doesn't work.

I also tried all those things while removing any code that I thought could possibly be interfering in any way. NOTHING seems to solve it.

Here is my current code. The function I am calling in the "onclick" is at the very bottom of the javascript file.
http://dylanmadigan.net/_digital-work/game-2/6-menus/index.html

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the body of your post.

Answer (score 0):

your div with id `home-page-bg` is overshadowing your div with `home-page-contents`. Not only this is causing the issue but that keyframe animation makes it difficult since it is  on top of the menu.

Take out this div with the keyframe applied and see how it works..
hmm...

Also Trying experimenting with a still background